# Prove $\langle x,y\mid x^n=y^2=1,xy=yx^2\rangle$ is of order $6$ for $n=3k$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

From Abstract Algebra Third Edition (Foote, Dummit). Section 1.3 Question 17.

> Let $X_{2n}$ be the group represented by $\langle x,y \mid x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2\rangle $. Prove that if $n = 3k$, then $X_{2n}$ has order $6$.

Here is my attempted proof.

> It is sufficient to show that $|x| = 3$, because then $X_{2n} = \{1,x,x^2,y,yx,yx^2\}$ which has order 6. Consider the following
>
> $$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} yx &= yxy^2 \\    &= y(xy)y \\   &= y(yx^2)y \\   &= y^2x^2y \\   &= x^2y \\   &= yx^4 \end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
>
> So we have $yx = yx^4$. By the cancellation laws, $x =  x^4 \implies x^3 = 1 \implies |x| \leq 3$.
>
> $|x| \neq 1$ because $x$ is not the identity. $|x| \neq 2$ because
> then $X_{2n} = \{1, x, y, yx\}$ which is of order $4 \neq 3k$. Then
> |x| is of order 3.
>
> Q.E.D.

The reason I feel uncertain of this proof is that I didn't use the hypothesis that $n=3k$ until the very end of the proof, and I was able to find a bound on the order of $x$ without knowing anything about the size of the group, using only the relations provided. I feel like if I did make a mistake, it has something to do with my assumptions of what $X_{2n}$ looks like, for example maybe $x=y$ for some values of n. The book did mention the "collapsing" (pg. 26) of relations, which might be what is going on.

Comment: No, it is not sufficient to prove that $x$ has order $3$; that would only show you the group has order *at most* six, and only after you proved that every element of $X_{2n}$ can be written in at least one of the forms you claim, which you never did. Showing $x$ has order $3$ only tells you that the first three elements you list are distinct, and that the last three are distinct, but it does not show that none of the last three equals any of the first $3$. What if $y$ is trivial?  You also can’t just say that $x$ is not the identity; you need to *prove* it.

Comment: Once you know that $x^3=e$, you know that $|x|$ **divides** $3$, so you know it is either $1$ or $3$; your explanation for why it can’t be $2$ doesn’t work, either. What you write is unjustified.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Any ideas for how to show that the $x^n$ elements are distinct from the $yx^n$ elements? Other than that, your comment helps me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: You’ve merely asserted that $x$ is not the identity. In fact, for any $n$ not a multiple of $3,$ $x$ is the identity. You have to find a reason it is not.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews, Arturo also pointed that out as well. I may need to start there.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve merely asserted that $x$ is not the identity. But if $n$ was not a multiple of $3,$ $x$ would be the identity.

One way to show $x$ is not the identity is to find a group $G$ with $|G|=6$ and $x,y\in G$ such that:

$$x^{3k}=1,y^2=1,xy=yx^2.$$

There is only one non-commutative group of order $6,$ so...